# How should I display a list of items with different statuses?

Tags: web-app, education

I'm working on a web based platform that is about asking for, giving and getting feedback on assignments. When requesting feedback, your request is parsed as an item in a table where you can see a status of this feedback. The table contains 3 different columns - status of feedback, #tag and date of last creation (if the item gets updated). When requesting feedback, the status is "Waiting for feedback". The different statuses include also "Received and unread feedback", "Read feedback", "Feedback given & sent" (you can also give feedback if someone request for you to do that).

Now the problem is that there isn't really any differentiation between statuses besides some pastel colors, which are hard to understand, especially when the table has many items. How should I make such table more comprehensible? Colors, icons, prioritization, fonts?  Or perhaps completely another approach e.g. something similar to a Kanban board?

P.S. In near future there will be a feature of adding different classrooms, so perhaps also a differentiation and filtering based on a classroom should be taken into account?

Comment: Is viewing status of item the primary goal of the list? If so, it should capter attention. Or is it just one of possible fields for filtering? If so, it shouldn't become visual noise.

Comment: I suppose the primary goal of the list is to see when you have received feedback so you can view it first. Everything else are other rows which are not that important, but it's good to see their statuses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is my take on how I would do it without knowing how your UI looks like.

- Use abbreviations with the status to differentiate
- Put them to the left of the table to allow for better scanning

[image: table with feedback]

Comment: This is a good approach. In addition to this you might also want to consider using colour more sparingly. Sometimes status columns like this can quickly turn in to a list of smarties and it can be a bit overwhelming for the user (this will depend on how many different status types are displayed at the same time in a typical table). If there are any statuses that requires more attention considering using colour for those and possibly use grey on standard statuses. This will make the statuses that require action stand out a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the solution suggestion! This can also be coupled with the ability to filter by different classes and I suppose one way to minimize the amount of items in the table is to simply create more pages to scroll through. What would be your take on prioritization? What items in the table should be shown first? I imagine it's the received ones and they could also be in a bold font